# xenstore-read: undefined symbol: xs_open

Tags: xen

I have successfully compiled the xen hypervisor on Ubuntu 11.04.

However, I can't get it to run properly.

the xencommons init script shows
Starting xenstored...............................................
Could not start xenstored

On further investigation it seems the init script simply starts xenstore-read like this

> xenstore-read -s / >/dev/null 2>&1

Obviously all output is going to /dev/null

Running this directly i.e. xenstore-read -s / provides the following output

xenstore-read: symbol lookup error: xenstore-read: undefined symbol: xs_open

Searching through google turned up fruitless.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you build the Xen tools, though?  Sounds like you might have gotten a package and jammed it in when the dependencies suggested it wouldn't work, or did a local build of the tools and then whip out the library rug from under their feet.

Comment: Just downloaded the sources and built according to a blog.  I'm going to try doing an ubuntu upgrade first.  Perhaps a library is missing.

Comment: Close enough.  Rebuilding helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's only need to rebuild the xenstore.

```
cd xen-4.1.1/tools/xenstore
make clean
make install
```

Then it's works. I don't know why but it's can work after rebuilt and reinstalled.